# UITableViewCell not scrolling content when entering Edit Mode

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've implemented some tableview editing, deletion specifically, but when the UITableViewCell subclass enters editing mode, it does not 'shift' the content of the cell.

In the past, I've experienced this when the subviews are added to the cell itself rather then the contentView, but in this case, all subviews are indeed on the cell's contentView.

For what it is worth, this was a cell created in interface builder.

Anyone know of the fix to this?

Thanks!

Here is the relevant recursive description:

```
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <DDPaymentCardCell: 0x125e6c690; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 35; 320 44); autoresize = W; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17805b660>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1782240e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x125e6c990; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x178241920>; layer = <CALayer: 0x17822a4c0>; contentOffset: {82, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView: 0x1781ac400; frame = (320 0; 82 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x17803dd40>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationButton: 0x125e50f30; frame = (0 0; 82 43.5); opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; layer = <CALayer: 0x17803dec0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x125e32880; frame = (15 11; 52 22); text = 'Delete'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17822ce20>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x178174c40; frame = (38 0; 282 43.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x178240180>; layer = <CALayer: 0x17822c840>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x125e3cb40; frame = (100 11; 227 21); text = 'Ending in 4242'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17803fe00>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x125e19620; frame = (61 12; 32 20); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1782256a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x125e55e90; frame = (248 11; 86 21); text = 'Exp 4/2024'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x178229740>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x178191100; frame = (82 43.5; 320 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x17822bd20>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x170190b50; frame = (82 0; 320 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x170236e00>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellEditControl: 0x125d2f370; frame = (0 0; 47 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17023d360>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x125d31640; frame = (12 14; 22 22); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x170232300>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x125d20c20; frame = (12 12; 22 22); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17023acc0>>
```

Comment: Some code/screenshots would be nice. And in a crapshoot, did you add the autolayout constraints/autoresizing masks?

Comment: @Can Autolayout constraints should also be against the content view, so that should not be, theoretically :), the problem.

Comment: Sean, could you possible enter editing, reproduce the bug, hit pause, and post the debug output of `po [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow recursiveDescription]`? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, the answer is to ensure that you're using AutoLayout correctly. If you add a constraint:

```
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.priceLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:-kCellRightMargin]];
```

Eveything will work as desired